# How do I handle page not found error when using Laravel 4 Resource Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, controller, http-status-code-404

I have this resourceful route to a controller

```
Route::resource ('users', 'UsersController');
```

UsersController has all the actions handled by Resource controller

```
Verb              Path                     Action      RouteName
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
GET               /users                  index        users.index
GET               /users/create           create       users.create
POST              /users                  store        users.store
GET               /users /{id}            show         users.show
GET               /users {id}/edit        edit         users.edit
PUT/PATCH         /users /{id}            update       users.update
DELETE            /users /{id}            destroy      users.destroy
```

My problem and question refers to the `show($id)` action, what’s the best way to handle a situation where for instance a user requests for example:

**http://example.com/users/anyunexpectedinput**

and the show action method is like this

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    //should I do this
    If(!is_object($user)) App::abort(404, 'Page not found');

    //OR

    //Return a view with message “user not found”

}
```

Nb: Am still learning Laravel so please accept my apologies if this is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd always throw an (404) exception. Pro's:

1. You can use `catch` or in case of `App::abort`, `App::error`, to handle the error
2. Laravel itself will also throw the same exception sometimes, so you are consistent
3. You don't have to return something. Say you have a helper function somewhere. There you can't just simply return a view, but throwing an exception will still work and stop the execution immediately.

Also you can make use of `findOrFail` which automatically throws a 404 exception if no model is found:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best way is to throw 404 error (`NotFoundHttpException`). Why? For example [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-model-binding) if user with specified ID doesn't exist it will throw 404 error.

> Note: If a matching model instance is not found in the database, a 404 error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to display not found messages following the model exception.

In your route :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    $error= BaseController::getException($e);
    return View::make('404')->with('error', $error); ;
});
```

In your BaseController :

```
static public function getException($e)
    {
        if(!$e->getModel())
            return;

        // Users
        if($e->getModel() == "User")
            return('This user doesn\'t exist');

        // Blog posts, ...
        if($e->getModel() == "Post")
            return('This post doesn\'t exist');
    }
```

In your 404 view :

```
<p>{{{ $error  or 'Page not found' }}}</p>
```